# ¿Cómo puedo simplificar este código con "ifelse"?

Tags: r, condiciones, else

tengo un data frame de más de 30.000 datos cuya estructura es una columna con meses y otra columna con años:

```
> data
    m    y
1   6 2015
2   6 2016
3   7 2015
4   7 2015
5   8 2015
6   8 2016
7   6 2017
8   6 2017
9   6 2016
...
```

Me gustaría añadirle una columna llamada "fecha" de tipo Character que sea tal que así:

```
  m    y    fecha
1   6 2015  Jun./15
2   6 2016  Jun./16
3   7 2015  Jul./15
4   7 2015  Jul./15
5   8 2015  Ago./15
6   8 2016  Ago./16
7   6 2017  Jun./17
8   6 2017  Jun./17
9   6 2016  Jun./16
...
```

Con pocos datos de un par de años lo he hecho utilizando ifelse:

```
data<-data %>% mutate(fecha = ifelse(m=="1" & y=="2020","Ene./20",ifelse(m=="1" & y=="2019","Ene./19",
                  ifelse(m=="2" & y=="2020","Feb./20",ifelse(m=="2" & y=="2019","Feb./19",
                  ifelse(m=="3" & y=="2020","Mar./20",ifelse(m=="3" & y=="2019","Mar./19",
                  ifelse(m=="4" & y=="2020","Abr./20",ifelse(m=="4" & y=="2019","Abr./19",
                  ifelse(m=="5" & y=="2020","May./20",ifelse(m=="5" & y=="2019","May./19",
                  ifelse(m=="6" & y=="2020","Jun./20",ifelse(m=="6" & y=="2019","Jun./19",
                  ifelse(m=="7" & y=="2020","Jul./20",ifelse(m=="7" & y=="2019","Jul./19",
                  ifelse(m=="8" & y=="2020","Ago./20",ifelse(m=="8" & y=="2019","Ago./19",
                  ifelse(m=="9" & y=="2020","Sep./20",ifelse(m=="9" & y=="2019","Sep./19",
                  ifelse(m=="10" & y=="2020","Oct./20",ifelse(m=="10" & y=="2019","Oct./19",
                  ifelse(m=="11" & y=="2020","Nov./20", ifelse(m=="11" & y=="2019","Nov./19",
                  ifelse(m=="12" & y=="2020","Dic./20",  ifelse(m=="12" & y=="2019","Dic./19",
                  "")))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Pero cuando tengo muchos años me da el siguiente error al encadenar muchas veces "ifelse":

```
Error: desbordamiento contextstack en la línea 9
```

Me gustaría encontrar la manera fácil de hacerlo,quizás utilizando sapply, pero no lo consigo. ¿Podría alguen ayudarme?. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar estructuras condicionales no es lo más cómodo en este caso. Si, como parece ser tu ejemplo, el año siempre es superior al 2000, podrías hacer algo así:

```
meses <- c('Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 
           'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic')
data %>% 
  mutate(fecha = paste0(meses[m], './',y - 2000))
```

- Usamos la variable `m` como índice para ubicar el mes, de un vector previamente definido
- restamos 2000 al año para quedarnos con la centuria.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! ha funcionado a las mil maravillas!!. Después de darle vueltas durante toda la tarde-noche lo acabo de solucionar con tu respuesta en 5 minutos.